# Cannot cast struct pointer to PUCHAR

Tags: c++, windows, driver, kernel-mode

I'm testing a code (based in this [reference](http://www.m5home.com/bbs/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=8953&pid=50792)) and i'm receiving a error that says:

> 'type cast': cannot convert from 'SYSTEM_SERVICE_TABLE' to 'PUCHAR'

How can solve it?

**Edition:**

The goal is try find **Shadow SSDT** table address on Windows 10 32bit.

```
#include <ntddk.h>

#define NTOSAPI __declspec(dllimport)

typedef struct tag_SYSTEM_SERVICE_TABLE {
    PULONG ServiceTable;
    PULONG CounterTable;
    ULONG ServiceLimit;
    PCHAR ArgumentTable;
} SYSTEM_SERVICE_TABLE, *PSYSTEM_SERVICE_TABLE, **PPSYSTEM_SERVICE_TABLE;

NTOSAPI SYSTEM_SERVICE_TABLE KeServiceDescriptorTable;

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {

    NTSTATUS NtStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    pDriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;
    
    DbgPrint("DriverEntry()!\n");

    PUCHAR p = NULL;
    PSYSTEM_SERVICE_TABLE KeServiceDescriptorTableWIN32K = NULL;
    
    for (p = (PUCHAR)KeServiceDescriptorTable - PAGE_SIZE; p < (PUCHAR)KeServiceDescriptorTable + PAGE_SIZE; p++)
    {
        if (p != (PUCHAR)KeServiceDescriptorTable)
        {
            if (memcmp(p, &KeServiceDescriptorTable, sizeof(SYSTEM_SERVICE_TABLE)) == 0)
            {
                KeServiceDescriptorTableWIN32K = (PSYSTEM_SERVICE_TABLE)(p + sizeof(SYSTEM_SERVICE_TABLE));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return NtStatus;
}
```

Comment: Why do have those `()` in your post?

Comment: People add garbage data to get around the filter that asks them to add more explanation.

Comment: Do you understand what the code is supposed to be doing? If you do then could you take the time to explain. If you don't then how will you know if any suggested change is correct?

Comment: @Davison Instead, you should fully explain your problem. When you did research to answer this question, where did you get stuck?

Comment: `KeServiceDescriptorTable` is not a pointer. Attempting to treat it as such is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title says "Cannot cast struct **pointer** to PUCHAR", but the code is not trying to cast a **pointer**, it is trying to cast the **struct itself**, which is why the compiler complains.  You need to get **the address** of the struct and cast that instead, ie:

```
(PUCHAR)&KeServiceDescriptorTable
```